# How to include class header files in other class header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile

I'm using the C/C++ Makefile Project extension for Visual Studio Code running on Linux which generates me a C++ Project with some preset folders in my case. I'm also using the g++ compiler to work with this makefile extension.

I'm doing a project where I have a `Counter` class and an `AutoCounter` class, that are in separated `.h` files. In the `AutoCounter` class I need to create a private object of the `Counter` class.

My first thought was to `#include "Counter.h"` in the `AutoCounter.h` file so I could create the private `Counter` object.

```cpp
//AutoCounter.h
#pragma once
#include "include/Counter.h"

class AutoCounter
{
private:
    Counter count; //object from class Counter
public:
    ( . . . )
};
```

However, when I `make` the whole project, the compiler says:

```
src/include/AutoCounter.h:4:10: fatal error: include/Counter.h: File or Folder not found
    4 | #include "include/Counter.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I've also tried to include the `Counter.h` in the `main.cpp` file but still has the same error.

This is weird because in `main.cpp` there is no issues including this header.

As I said before, I'm using the C/C++ Makefile Project extension, which only recommends me to change this:

```
########################################################################
####################### Makefile Template ##############################
########################################################################

# Compiler settings - Can be customized.
CC = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14 -Wall -g
LDFLAGS = 

# Makefile settings - Can be customized.
APPNAME = main
EXT = .cpp
SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
```

Comment: "I've also tried to include the Counter.h in the **main.cpp** file but still has the same error. //

This is weird because in **main.cpp** there is no issues including this header." -> that's contradictory information.

Comment: What's the folder structure?

Comment: @user202729 What I meant was that including `Counter.h` in `main.cpp` there are no problems including it in main, but there are still problems including it in the `AutoCounter.h` file. I concluded doing this, that this problem only happens in `.h` type files. The folder project structure is created by the makefile extension: 

*folder:*
    -obj
    -src:(
        main.cpp
        Counter.cpp
        AutoCounter.cpp
        -include: (
            Counter.h
            AutoCounter.h ) )
Makefile

Comment: What's error message if you include "Counter.h" in the other file? // Makefile extension?

Comment: @user202729 The error only happens if I include in `.h` files and the message its the same changing only the file where the error occurred. I referred in my question that I was using the `C/C++ Makefile Project` extension for Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the docs for your compiler you'll see that the `#include "..."` form searches for included headers *in the same directory as the file currently being processed*.

When you are compiling `main.cpp` and you `#include "include/Counter.h"`, it works because that file exists in relation to where `main.cpp` is.

When you are compiling `include/AutoCounter.h` and you add `#include "include/Counter.h"`, that won't work because in relation to `include/Counter.h` the file `include/AutoCounter.h` doesn't exist: the compiler is looking for `include/include/AutoCounter.h`.

If you want to use this type of relative include path, then in the `include/AutoCounter.h` file you need just `#include "Counter.h"`, because `AutoCounter.h` is already in the `include` directory.

**ETA**

The above is definitely your problem.  If the fix didn't work you must have applied it incorrectly.  Here's a sample I put together to show it:

```
$ echo '#include "include/AutoCounter.h"' > main.cpp

$ mkdir include

$ echo '#include "include/Counter.h"' > include/AutoCounter.h

$ touch include/Counter.h

$ gcc -c -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:1:
include/AutoCounter.h:1:10: fatal error: include/Counter.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "include/Counter.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Now fix it:

```
$ echo 'include "Counter.h"' > include/AutoCounter.h

$ gcc -c -o main.o main.cpp
$
```

Comment: I tried to do that but I still got the same error! Is there anything else that could be? I'm using this Makefile extension because I saw it on a video, but in the video they don't approach this issue I'm having, should I use another makefile template? I don't know that much about makefiles, that's why I'm using makefile creators

Comment: It has nothing to do with the makefile.  If you run those commands from the command line you'll get the same error.  Once you know what the compile command and code should be, then you can ensure the makefile invokes them the right way.  Before you know what the compile commands and code should be, it's useless to try to write a makefile for them.  Make just runs the commands you tell it to: it doesn't magically fix wrong commands.  There's no way you could get the exact same error after you make the change I suggested.

Comment: I changed some arguments to makefile trying to solve this issue and forgot to change it again to the original. Your solution works!